# volatile barrier in Hibernate source code would "syncs state with other threads". How?

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, jpa, volatile

I was digging inside the source code of `hibernate-jpa` today and stumbled upon the following code snippet (that you can also find [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?source_dir=hibernate-jpa-api-master/src/main/java/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProviderResolverHolder.java)):

```
private static class PersistenceProviderResolverPerClassLoader implements PersistenceProviderResolver {

    //FIXME use a ConcurrentHashMap with weak entry
    private final WeakHashMap<ClassLoader, PersistenceProviderResolver> resolvers =
            new WeakHashMap<ClassLoader, PersistenceProviderResolver>();
    private volatile short barrier = 1;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public List<PersistenceProvider> getPersistenceProviders() {
        ClassLoader cl = getContextualClassLoader();
        if ( barrier == 1 ) {} //read barrier syncs state with other threads
        PersistenceProviderResolver currentResolver = resolvers.get( cl );
        if ( currentResolver == null ) {
            currentResolver = new CachingPersistenceProviderResolver( cl );
            resolvers.put( cl, currentResolver );
            barrier = 1;
        }
        return currentResolver.getPersistenceProviders();
    }
```

That weird statement `if ( barrier == 1 ) {} //read barrier syncs state with other threads` disturbed me. I took the time to dig into the `volatile` keyword specification.

To put it simply, in my understanding, it ensures that any `READ` or `WRITE` operation on the corresponding variable will allways be performed directly in the memory at the place the value is usually stored. It specifically prevents accesses through caches or registrars that hold a copy of the value and are not necessarily aware if the value has changed or is being modified by a concurrent thread on another core.

As a consequence it causes a drop in performances because every access implies to go all the way into the memory instead of using the usual (pipelined?) shortcuts. But it also ensures that whenever a thread reads the variable it will always be up to date.

I provided those details to let you know what my understanding of the keyword is. But now when I re-read the code I am telling myself "*Ok wo we are slowing the execution by ensuring that a value which is always 1 is always 1 (and setting it to 1). How does that help?*"

Anybody can explain this?

Comment: All memory is dumped when acessing a volatile field, search on SO that you find the links for the Java Specification

Comment: Oh I forgot to write that in the question. And so how does that helps?

Comment: Your non volatile fields will be synced also

Comment: No, that is not "the source code of JPA". That is some code in HIBERNATE's implementation of JPA. Other JPA providers do NOT do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You understand `volatile` wrong.

> it ensures that any READ or WRITE operation on the corresponding
>   variable will allways be performed directly in the memory at the place
>   the value is usually stored. It specifically prevents accesses through
>   caches or registrars that hold a copy of the value and are not
>   necessarily aware if the value has changed or is being modified by a
>   concurrent thread on another core.

You are talking about the **implemention**, while the implemention may differs from jvm to jvm.

---

`volatile` is much like some kind of specification or rule, it can [gurantee](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/atomic.html) that

> Write to a volatile variable establishes a happens-before relationship
>   with subsequent reads of that same variable. This means that changes
>   to a volatile variable are always visible to other threads. What's
>   more, it also means that when a thread reads a volatile variable, it
>   sees not just the latest change to the volatile, **but also the side
>   effects of the code that led up the change.**

and

> Using simple atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing
>   these variables through synchronized code, but requires more care by
>   the programmer to avoid memory consistency errors. Whether the extra
>   effort is worthwhile depends on the size and complexity of the
>   application.

---

In this case, `volatile` is not used to gurantte `barrier == 1`:

```
if ( barrier == 1 ) {} //read
PersistenceProviderResolver currentResolver = resolvers.get( cl );
if ( currentResolver == null ) {
    currentResolver = new CachingPersistenceProviderResolver( cl );
    resolvers.put( cl, currentResolver );
    barrier = 1; //write
}
```

it is used to gurantee that the side effects between the read and write is visible to other threads.

Without it, if you put something in the `resolvers` in Thread1, Thread2 might not notice it.

With it, if Thread2 read `barrier` after Thread1 write it, Thread2 is gurantted to see this `put` action.

---

And, there are many other synchronization mechanism, such as:

- `synchronized` keyword
- `ReentrantLock`
- `AtomicInteger`
- ....

Usually, they can also build this happens-before relation ship between different threads.

Comment: Your last code block is not properly idented, which may lead a reader to believe something happens inside the if(barrier==1) block, which is not the case.

Comment: For completeness I would suggest that you also quote the sentence "_Using simple atomic variable access is more efficient than accessing these variables through synchronized code, **but requires more care by the programmer to avoid memory consistency errors**. Whether the extra effort is worthwhile depends on the size and complexity of the application_". Actually this is the main point I was trying to understand: that piece of code decrease the risk of consistency error, but does not totally prevent it, am I wrong?

Comment: @Aldian I just updated my answer. And, yes, it does not prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

This is done to make updates done to `resolvers` map to other threads by establishing **happens before** relationship (https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-multi-threading/happens-before.html).

In a single thread the following instructions have happens before relation

```
resolvers.put( cl, currentResolver );
barrier = 1;
```

But to make change in `resolvers` visible to other threads we need to read value from volatile variable `barrier` because write and subsequent read of the same volatile variable establish happens before relation (which is also transitive). So basically this is the overall result:

1. Update `resolvers`
2. Write to volatile `barrier`
3. Read from volatile `barrier` to make update made in step 1 visible to a thread which reads value from `barrier`

Comment: What you are saying makes sense. Except that one could wonder if there was not a simpler way to read `barrier` than performing a `if`.. And that I am still not convinced that two threads performing the very same operations at the same time would not be able to concurrently call `resolvers.put( cl, currentResolver );` before the `barrier = 1;` statement

Comment: @Aldian `if` could be replaced by `short dummy = barrier;` but not sure that this will raise less questions than `if`. Yes, if two threads will execute that at the same time two objects `new CachingPersistenceProviderResolver( cl )` will be created. To avoid that `ConcurrentHashMap` or `synchronized` block should be used.

Answer (score 1):

Volatile variables - is lightweight form of synchronization in Java.

Declaring a field `volatile` will give the following effects:

- Compiler will not reorder the operations
- Variable will be not cashed in registers
- Operations on 64-bit data structures will be executed as atomic one
- It will affect visibility synchronization of other variables

Quote from Brian Goetz's *Concurrency in practice*:

> The visibility effects of volatile variables extend beyond the value
>   of the volatile variable itself. When thread A writes to a volatile
>   variable and subsequently thread B reads that same variable, the
>   values of all variables that were visible to A prior to writing to the
>   volatile variable become visible to B after reading the volatile
>   variable.

Okay, what is the point of keeping `1` and not declare `resolvers` as `volatile WeakHashMap`?

This safe publication guarantee applies only to primitive fields and object references. For the purposes of this visibility guarantee, the actual member is the object reference; the objects referred to by volatile object references are beyond the scope of the safe publication guarantee. Consequently, declaring an object reference to be volatile is insufficient to guarantee that changes to the members of the referent are published to other threads. A thread may fail to observe a recent write from another thread to a member field of such an object referent.

Furthermore, when the referent is mutable and lacks thread safety, other threads might see a partially constructed object or an object in a inconsistent state.

The instance of the `Map` object is mutable because of its `put()` method.

Interleaved calls to `get()` and `put()` may result in the retrieval of internally inconsistent values from the Map object because `put()` modifies its state. Declaring the object reference `volatile` is insufficient to eliminate this data race.

Since `volatile` variable establishes a `happens-before` relationship, when one thread has an update, it's just can inform others accessing `barrier`.

> From a memory visibility perspective, writing a volatile
>   variable is like exiting a synchronized block and reading a volatile
>   variable is like entering a synchronized block.